# Android Common XML Editor opened without graphical and source on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a really wired issue.

Everything worked fine yesterday, but today when I opened the Eclipse and trying to open a layout it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is nothing shown(Not the name of the layout, not design and graphical tabs).
I already tried the following:

- To upgrade everything in the SDK manager.
- To restart everything including my computer(which in most of the time fix any problem in eclipse).
- Shift+Alt+F7 doesn't work.

**UPDATE**:
Add to done list:

- Re-Open Perspective
- Window>> Reset Perspective

This is my Error Log:

[image]

Comment: did you close and re-open perspective? might help

Comment: Yes, Now but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

right click on the layout you want to open and choose

`Open with >> Android Common XML Editor`,

try this as well

```
Window>> Reset Perspective
```

sometime graphical layout show. but nothing showing. only blank. this is happen because the manifest minimum sdk is not support to view the layout.to resolve that change the api level which display in the right corner of layout display area.

Comment: It's tried to open it as "Android Common XML Editor" and that the result. 
Reset perspective doesn't work for me

Comment: while you saved your project for the last time, did you face and power outage, or sudden error due to which eclipse closed or restarted ?

Comment: try to locate your layout file in your system and check it's size, if it is close to zero then you most probably lost the data in it

Comment: I'm sure that the data not lost, cause if I open the layout via text editor I see the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97824/discussion-between-pankaj-nimgade-and-user2235615).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that found:

1. Convert the project to Android Studio.(I don't take it because I've a complex project)
2. I Re-install the Eclipse.

Hope that it will help someone to save some time.